# GGplot2-Legends w/ Multi Variables-Two Lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with bubble charts and I made up this one to ask this question. How would you get it so that the legend with two variables is also two lines? I would love for the legend to read

Cut: (color scheme)

line break

Price: (Size scheme)

```
test <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = depth, size = price, fill = cut)) 
+     geom_point(shape=21) + theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

I've tried adding:

```
+ guide_legend(nrow = 2)
```

and that gave me:

```
Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot
```

Comment: might help: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-legend-easy-steps-to-change-the-position-and-the-appearance-of-a-graph-legend-in-r-software

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `legend.box = "vertical"`.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = depth, size = price, fill = cut)) +     
     geom_point(shape=21) + 
     theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "vertical")
```

[image]